# Too long time for loading the data markers in artoolkit for android

Tags: android, artoolkit

I'm developing an android app using artoolkit. I started from nftSimpleProj, and i added some markers to DataNFT (26). It works fine, but for loading all markers the app spends a lot of time and for that the camera preview is shown after a long time. The markers are read by native `nativeVideoInit(capWidth, capHeight, cameraIndex, frontFacing);` function. My questioin is the following: How i can move this function in order to execute it only one time in the app life cycle?